# Have a lot of variables that are in order. I need to convert them using JavaScript to contain something else but don't want to do it one by one

Tags: javascript

First of all I'm not a programmer. I need to use some really basic HTML, CSS and XML for my work. The program I am using allows running javascripts, too.

I usually have a lot of variables from my XML files. They go by something like this:

```
VAL001
VAL002
VAL003
VAL004
```

You get it.
These variables are often checkboxes. The values can be either 'Checked' or 'Unchecked'.
Instead of embedding these variables in the HTML code, I tend to convert it to something else so it gets nicer. Like this:

```
if ( VAL001 == 'Checked' ) CHK001 = '&#10003;';
else CHK001 = '';
```

When this is done, I insert CHK001 (instead of VAL001) in the HTML so I get a nice check mark if the box was checked and nothing when it was not checked. When there are a lot of these boxes it's not too effective to do it one by one.

What I tried in JavaScript is:

```
var i;
for ( i = 1, i <= 9, i++ ) {
  if ( VAL00$i == 'Checked' ) CHK00$i = '&#10003;'
  else CHK00$i = '';
}
var j;
for ( j = 10, j <= 99, j++ ) {
  if ( VAL0$j == 'Checked' ) CHK0$j = '&#10003;'
  else CHK0$j = '';
}
```

I thought that this would replace the last digits with i and j and I would get what I need. Unfortunately this just brings up a ReferenceError saying that VAL00$i can't be found.

If I replace the $i and $j with [i] and [j] I get the same ReferenceError but this time i and j are not told to be wrong so I get that VAL00 can't be found. A simple solution would really speed up things for me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @korsz and welcome to StackOverflow! In order to answer this question we need some more information about your environment. What program is this JS running in? This is important for us to know so that we can tell whether these variables are passed in or are also saved somewhere else etc.

Comment: `I usually have a lot of variables from my XML files.` how and where these variables are declared?

Comment: The program was made by a developer at the company I am working for so it is not a widely used one. He left the company 3 months ago so I can't ask him how it works. In the xml file I just create a line `<input var="VAL001" value="null" dataid="random_number" type="checkbox"  />` and boom, the program that reads it have a checkbox now. While the workers are using this program, the values gets stored in a .tmp file and when they complete the program this gets converted to a simple .txt file. The txt contains all the data seperated by line breaks as `dataid:random_number:VAL001:Checked'

Answer (score 0):

You could put your variables in an array and use map to check and change the variables to be a tick or not.

```
var array = [
    VAL001,
    VAL002,
    VAL003,
    VAL004
];

var newArray = array.map(val=>{
    if (val === 'Checked') return '&#10003;';
    else return '';
});
```

Alteratively, if you need to know the names of the variables after checking everything you could use an object.

```
var obj = {
    VAL001: VAL001,
    VAL002: VAL002,
    VAL003: VAL003,
    VAL004: VAL004
};
var newObj;
for (var i of Object.keys(obj){
    if (obj[i] === 'Checked') newObj[i] = '&#10003;';
    else newObj[i] = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are lacking some information about your environment, but assuming your framework gives you a set of global variables, this should get you started:

```
for (var i=1, i<=99, i++) {
  var i_padded = i.toString().padStart(3, 0);
  if (window["VAL" + i_padded] == 'Checked') {
    window["CHK" + i_padded] = '&#10003;';
  } else {
    window["CHK" + i_padded] = "";
  }
}
```

In order to access your global variables I am using the `window` object here. This is assuming you are running this JS in a browser or browser-like environment.

Comment: We have `.padStart()` extension method for `string`. All you need to do is `i.toString().padStart(3, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having `VAL001` variables as property in `obj` then you can perform like below.

Here `i.toString().padStart(3, 0)`, for `i = 1` it will return `001` similarly for `i=10` it will return `010`; You can access property of object with `obj[propertyName]`. So these values will be accessible with obj[`VAL${index}`].

```js
var obj = {
  VAL001: 'Checked',
  VAL002: '',
  VAL003: 'Checked',
  VAL004: '',
  VAL010: '',
  VAL099: 'Checked',
};

var result = {};

for (var i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
  let index = i.toString().padStart(3, 0);

  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(`VAL${index}`)) {
    if (obj[`VAL${index}`] == 'Checked') result[`CHK${index}`] = '&#10003;'
    else result[`CHK${index}`] = '';
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

If you are having `variables` in global scope then you can use `windows["VAL001"]`.

```js
var VAL001 = 'Checked',
  VAL002 = '',
  VAL003 = 'Checked',
  VAL004 = '',
  VAL010 = '',
  VAL099 = 'Checked';

for (var i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
  let index = i.toString().padStart(3, 0);

  if (window.hasOwnProperty(`VAL${index}`)) {
    if (window[`VAL${index}`] == 'Checked') window[`CHK${index}`] = '&#10003;'
    else window[`CHK${index}`] = '';

    console.log(`CHK${index} = ` + window[`CHK${index}`]);
  }
}
```